# Python 3: Clean exit through input-command with asyncio

Tags: python, exit

I'm having trouble getting a clean exit through an input-command back to the terminal when executing a Python script which uses asyncio.

The script does a bunch of stuff but also provides an CLI for input.
Typing 'done' and pressing enter should shutdown the entire script.
I've tried to do so with the code underneath, but it does not seem to work.

The code for the script:

```
try:
    cm_cli = CmCli(iot_net, loop, logger)
    cm_cli.start()

    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("[CerberOS_Manager] Shutting everything down.")
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.close()
    loop.stop()
    sys.exit()
```

The code executed in cm_cli when typing 'done':

```
def run(self):
    print("[CM_CLI] Type 'help' for available commands, 'test' to run test.")
    while True:
        print('\033[0m', end=' ')     # stop printing yellow
        params = (input('>> '))
        print('\033[1;33m', end=' ')  # start printing yellow

        params = params.split()
        if len(params) < 1:
            continue

        if  params[0] == "help":
            print("[CM_CLI] Available commands are:")
        elif  params[0] == "":
            continue
        elif  params[0] == "done":
            print("[CM_CLI] Exiting.")
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        else:
            print("[CM_CLI] Unknown command.")
```

What happens at the moment when I simply start the script (called cerberos_manager.py) and type done:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/git/yggdrasil_managers/cerberos_mgmt $ sudo python3 cerberos_manager.py
[CM_CLI] Type 'help' for available commands, 'test' to run test.
 >> done
 [CM_CLI] Exiting.
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/pi/git/yggdrasil_managers/cerberos_mgmt/cm_cli.py", line 57, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So it raises the interrupt but does not manage to reach the printout in the other part. I've experimented with closing the loop in cm_cli but got no closer. Any suggestions for a clean exit back to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
import asyncio

def hello_world(loop):
    print('Hello World')
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Schedule a call to hello_world()
loop.call_soon(hello_world, loop)

# Blocking call interrupted by loop.stop()
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

You should catch exception in the callback function (`run()`) and fire `loop.stop()` in it. After that use `loop.close()` in the main module.